Why does Autodesk 2 factor authentication sometimes immediately turn off when enabled?
I hadn't enabled the 2-step verification before, so doing it for the first time.
I go to the page My Profile and settings > Security > 2-step verification.
I enabled it and added it to my authenticator app on my smart phone (tested in both Android and IOS).
The UI shows that 2-step verification is enabled:

but it shows it's turned off again after I refresh the page.

When I try to login to my Autodesk account though, it asks me for the verification code from the Authenticator App

But if I try to access an ACC project with 2-step verification required, I see this error: 2-step authentication not set up

Other members of the team have successfully implemented 2fa.
Existing reports on this

This sounds like a product side, login issue. Better to contact Autodesk support.  (Not as API.) Are you able to login to manage.autodesk.com?  If so, please login, and check to see if you see an option "open support cases", choose that.  (Should at the top of the page under Summary.) Once you get a page which says "Support Requests" page", then choose "Technical Product Support". (As a ADN, you should have that option.)  (it might take time to sync to work with ACC, but I'm not 100% sure...)
